# in Javascript, is `let a;` ever any different to `let a=undefined;`

Tags: javascript

Are the statements:

`let a;`

and

`let a=undefined;`

*ever* any different? Do they *always* compile to the same code in node and/or the browser?

Comment: See [undefined value](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-4.3.9).

Comment: From the duplicate, the important part is the [spec](https://es5.github.io/#x4.3.9) link and description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[They are equivalent.](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-declarations-and-the-variable-statement).

> A variable defined by a LexicalBinding with an Initializer is assigned the value of its Initializer's AssignmentExpression when the LexicalBinding is evaluated, not when the variable is created. If a LexicalBinding in a let declaration does not have an Initializer the variable is assigned the value undefined when the LexicalBinding is evaluated.

Where initializing `let` runs either the step:

> Perform ? InitializeReferencedBinding(lhs, undefined).

(in the case of `LexicalBinding : BindingIdentifier`), or the step

> Perform ? InitializeReferencedBinding(lhs, value).

where `value` is what's on the right-hand side of the `=`.

I suppose one very strange situation where they could be different is if someone created another identifier named `undefined`, but in any remotely sensible code, that shouldn't be seen.

```js
{
  const undefined = 5;
  let a = undefined;
  console.log(a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance. I am suprised one can declare a variable named `undefined`, I would have expected it to be a reserved word. Good to know.